# C#Regex Expression Getting certain words from a file path

Tags: c#, regex, arraylist, foreach

Hey guys im writing a c# application and i cant seem to split up data using regex as id like to.

```
C:\Users\e014425c\Downloads\StoreData\ABE1102013.csv
```

Thats getting stored as a string within the loop. I want:-

```
 ABE1
 10
 2013
```

From there i would store the individual strings into 3 arrays.
Problem is, within the loop the data will change so you cant use `Contains("ABE1")`

Help would be much appreciated!

```
foreach (string word in file)
{

    string testString = word;
    string firstWords = Regex.Match(testString, @"^(\w+\b.*?){6}").ToString();

    Console.Write(firstWords);
}
```

Thats how i´ve been testing the data

Comment: So you just want the [`FileNameWithoutExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: so you need only parts of the filename (ignoring the path)? What are the rules? First 4 characters, then next two characters or what? Don't let us guess, explain exactly what you are trying to do!

Comment: can you use the substring() function, will there always be 10 characters after removing the ext..? also show more examples of what the file names could look like since you say that you can't use the Contains Method

Comment: @DrKoch yes just parts of the file name ignoring the path, First 4 character then 2 Characters then 4 Characters, then store these words into different arrays   ABE1 - in array 1
 10 - in array 2
 2013 - in array 3

Comment: @MethodMan
C:\Users\e014425c\Downloads\StoreData\ABS1_52_2013.csv
C:\Users\e014425c\Downloads\StoreData\ACE1_6_2013.csv
C:\Users\e014425c\Downloads\StoreData\DBE1_7_2013.csv   The string would change each time it finishes a loop

Comment: are there always  underscores which delimit the interesting parts? Also it looks like part 2 can have 1 or two characters? Please specify what is possible, what are the corner cases? I.e. longest fields, shortest fields, etc.

Comment: @DrKoch yes theres always underscores,part 1 is always 4 fields with a int at the end(the letters range from a - z)  part 2 can have 1 or two fields that go from 1 to 52, part 3 goes from 2013 to 2014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get the filename only from the path:

```
string filename = File.FilenameWithoutExtension(path);
```

Then the characters you want with `SubString()`:

```
string a1 = filename.SubString(0, 4);
string a2 = filename.SubString(4, 2);
string a3 = filename.SubString(6, 4);
```

---

**EDIT**

With a general pattern "ABC1_xy_YYYY" it is better to use the underscores as delimiters:

```
 string[] field = filename.Split('_');
 a1 = field[0];
 ...
```